# MySQL Replace characters to match in where clause

Tags: mysql, database, string, where-clause

I have a table that has a column named 'name'.

Example:

```
ID   Name       Other      Field
1    that's      x           y
2    o-k         x           y
```

I want to be able to perform something like:

```
Select * FROM table WHERE Name like %thats%
```

And have the row with ID 1 as result, or execute:

```
 Select * FROM table WHERE Name like %ok%
```

and have the row with ID 2 as result.

So far I only managed to execute:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE( Name , '.', '' ) AS Name FROM table
```

That one returns the whole table with the points replaced for the Name column.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: no, the 3rd query returns all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up the `Name` string in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE REPLACE(
           REPLACE( Name, "-", "" ), "'", ""
       ) LIKE "%ok%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. It seems as though you want to search a replaced table?

```
SELECT Name FROM twinkle
WHERE Name EXISTS
    (SELECT Name FROM twinkle WHERE Name Like %thats%)
```